# replace array of object with another array of object base on property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to replace array of object with another array of object base on property?

```
var arr = [
    {'status':'ok'},
    {'status':'ok'},
    {'status':'error'}
]

var arr2 = [
    {'status':error, 'msg': 'etc', 'more property':true}
]

arr = arr.forEach((obj,i) => { if(obj.status === 'error'){obj = arr2[i]} return obj })
```

My above code failed, status ok is gone, I wonder what is wrong.

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: Can you tell us the expected output?

Comment: `arr2[i]` `i` is not defined. Also, `arr[2]` is also not there. Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: replace array of object of arr with arr2, base on status

Comment: @AlanJenshen Please read my previous comment properly. I suspected that missing `i` is a typo. But `arr[2]` is not available and will make it undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `Array#map()` to create a new array and `Array#find()` to find the object in the second array

```js
let arr=[{status:"ok"},{status:"ok"},{status:"error"}],
arr2=[{status:"error",msg:"etc","more property":!0}];

arr = arr.map(a=>{
  let fullObj = arr2.find(a2=>a2.status===a.status);
  return fullObj ? fullObj : a;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I found a problem with ur appraoch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517231/replace-multiple-array-of-object-using-multiple-array-of-object

Comment: @AlanJenshen I saw it. Please answer my comment

Comment: answer your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for assigning new properties to a given object.

```js
var arr = [{ status: 'ok' }, { status: 'ok' }, { status: 'error' }],
    arr2 = [{ status: 'error', msg: 'etc', 'more property': true }];

arr.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.status === 'error') {
        Object.assign(obj, arr2[0]);
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: arr[0] has restriction, why not use the index? what if i have 2 error status in arr, and arr2?

Comment: If this is the issue, assignment will also work. Yes, it may cause issues related to assignment with ref, but it should work for 1 like in OP's shared code.

Comment: @AlanJenshen, then you need a condition, which error object you want to be taken.

Comment: @Rajesh, no a simple assignment to `obj` does not work, because it is a local variable and an assignment changes only the variable, but not the referenced object.

Comment: My apologies Nina! Also @AlanJenshen just saw, `arr = arr.forEach`. `forEach` will not return anything. You are returning in callback, but this value will not be returned. So `arr` becomes `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
{'status':'ok'},
{'status':'ok'},
{'status':'error'}
]

var arr2 = [
{'status':error, 'msg': 'etc', 'more property':true}
]

arr = arr.forEach(obj => { if(obj.status === 'error'){obj = arr2[i]} return obj })
```

The callback in forEach() can take an additional arg for the index, but you forgot to provide it. So if you're trying to access the index you can do that.

Also, you're assigning arr to the output of forEach, but forEach() does not return anything, it just executes a callback for every element in the array. What you can do is swap it out for map, which is similar, but actually returns a new array.

Ex:

```
arr = arr.map((obj, i) => obj.status === 'error' ? arr2[i] : obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is replace the one with status "error" to be the arr2 object [0] so..

```
for(obj in arr){
    arr[obj] = arr[obj]['status'] == 'error' ? arr2[0] : arr[obj];
}
```