# replace multiple array of object using multiple array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I try to replace or overwrite array of object with array of object, like this

```
let arr = [{
    status: "ok"
  }, {
    status: "ok"
  }, {
    status: "error"
  }],
  arr2 = [{
    status: "error",
    msg: "im first msg",
    "more property": true
  }];

arr = arr.map(a => {
  let fullObj = arr2.find(a2 => a2.status === a.status);
  return fullObj ? fullObj : a;
});

console.log(arr); //working
```

The length of array of object which has property status equal to error will always be the same on arr, and arr2. But it will not work if I have multiple array of object

```
let arr = [{
    status: "ok"
  }, {
    status: "ok"
  }, {
    status: "error"
  }, {
    status: "error"
  }],
  arr2 = [{
    status: "error",
    msg: "im first msg",
    "more property": true
  }, {
    status: "error",
    msg: "im the second msg",
    "more property": true
  }];
```

Comment: What should be the output ? Concatenating the messages ?

Comment: what about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515597/replace-array-of-object-with-another-array-of-object-base-on-property)? if you need to replace by more than one object, you need more than one object and a condition, which object should be used.

Comment: what should be done with the third error?

Comment: what third error?

Comment: @Weedoze replace array of object of arr2 with array of object of arr

Comment: why do you overwrite ite original array? you are just replacing some content.

Comment: @NinaScholz replace the array of object.

Answer (score 1):

You could just shift the error array and take it as value for the item.

```js
let arr = [{ status: "ok" }, { status: "ok" }, { status: "error" }, { status: "error" }],
    arr2 = [{ status: "error", msg: "im first msg", "more property": true }, { status: "error", msg: "im the second msg", "more property": true }];
    
arr.forEach((a, i, aa) => {
    if (a.status === 'error') {
        aa[i] = arr2.shift();
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: look like a hack to me.

Comment: I did another approach: `arr.filter(obj => obj.status !== "error").concat(arr2)`

Comment: it changes the order of the objects in the array.